# How to create an IShellItemArray from a list of file names

Tags: c++, winapi, shell, windows-7, sdk

Could you please tell me how to delete multiple files with [**`IFileOperation::DeleteItems`**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/shobjidl_core/nf-shobjidl_core-ifileoperation-deleteitems)?

I'm not able to build **[`IShellItemArray`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/shobjidl_core/nn-shobjidl_core-ishellitemarray)** with file names.

Comment: Much easier to call SHFileOperation with a double zero-terminated list of files.

Comment: SHFileOperation is depreciated in Windows 7

Comment: `SHFileOperation` still works fine. If you don't need the new fangled features of `IFileOperation` then `SHFileOperation` is easier. I presume you know that `IFileOperation` is not available on XP.

Comment: If you really want to do it with `IFileOperation::DeleteItems`, your options are listed in [the documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/bb761106.aspx). Easiest in this case is probably `SHCreateShellItemArrayFromIDLists`. Get the ID Lists from `ILCreateFromPath`. Second choice would be `SHCreateShellItemArrayFromDataObject` where your data object contains a `CF_HDROP`. But it sounds like you aren't all that familiar with manipulating the shell namespace; you should familiarize yourself with that first. Shell items and item arrays and ID Lists are pretty fundamental.

Comment: I know that IFileOperation is not available on XP but I want to use IFileOperation, but I do not know how to build an IShellItemArray from a list of file names.

Comment: I just tried using `SHCreateShellItemArrayFromDataObject` with an `IDataObject` containing a bunch of paths in the `CF_HDROP` format as recommended by @Raymond Chen, but unfortunately the function errors out with "Invalid FORMATETC". Logging the calls to `GetData` in my data object shows that it only tries to retrieve clip format 49329 "Shell IDList Array".

Comment: @ErikJ Alas, you're right. `SHCreateShellItemArrayFromDataObject` doesn't support `CF_HDROP`. But it looks like `IFileOperation::DeleteItems` accepts a `DataObject` containing only `CF_HDROP` so you could wrap your list of file names inside a `CF_HDROP`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use **[SHCreateShellItemArrayFromIDLists](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb762146%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)**

Comment: See my comment to the original question. "Get the ID Lists from `ILCreateFromPath`." But if you're struggling with shell items and ID lists, I think you should step back and familiarize yourself with the basics before diving into advanced stuff like file operations. That way you'll know things like "when and how do I free this memory?"

Answer (score 1):

I got around this same problem. I created a variable (to hold all my IShellItems) of type vector and converted each filename ( also of a vector) using a for loop into an IShellItem object and kept them in the IShellItem container.
Then I loop through this IShellItem container, supplying each item to CopyItem().
After the loop, I then called PerformOpeations().